# Mejorar mi programa de la fecha en java

Tags: java

Resulta que debo de hacer un programa el cual te diga si la fecha es correcta y aparte controle si es bisiestos el año.

Lo que dice el ejercicio.

```
/*20.- Programa que reciba un dia, mes y anio y diga si 
la fecha es correcta (hay que tener en cuenta si el anio 
es bisiesto)
*/
```

El código.

```
/*20.- Programa que reciba un dia, mes y anio y diga si 
la fecha es correcta (hay que tener en cuenta si el anio 
es bisiesto)
 */
package boletin;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

/**
 *
 * @author javie
 */
public class Fecha {
int dia, mes, anio;
public Fecha(){
    
}
public Fecha(int dia,int mes,int anio){
    this.dia=dia;
    this.mes=mes;
    this.anio=anio;
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
         Fecha f = new Fecha();
        /*f.esBisiesto();
        f.fechaEscrita();*/
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduce la fecha y te digo si es correcta");
        System.out.print("Introduce el dia: ");
        f.dia = teclado.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Introduce el mes: ");
        f.mes = teclado.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Introduce el anio: ");
        f.anio = teclado.nextInt();
        String dateStr1 = "" + f.anio + "-" + f.mes + "-" + f.dia;
        String dateStr = "" + f.anio + f.mes + f.dia;
        DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE;
        try {
            LocalDate.parse(dateStr, dateFormatter);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // la fecha es inválida
            System.out.print("Fecha invalida");
        }
        System.out.print("Fecha valida");
// la fecha es válida
    }
}
```

Pero no me di cuenta a que se refería a todas las fechas posible no hasta la actual por lo que lo hice mal y me gustaría saber algún método para que te lo de la fecha correcta con un bucle for si es posible o con un while o de cualquier manera eficiente y aparte lo del año bisiesto. Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si puedes usar la API de java8 java.time.*, es bastante simple.

Para ver si es bisiesto:

```
Year.isLeap(anio)
```

Y para validar la fecha:

```
String dateStr = String.format("%s%02d%02d",  anio , mes , dia);
DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE;
try {
  LocalDate.parse(dateStr, dateFormatter);
} catch (Exception e) {
  // la fecha es inválida
}
// la fecha es válida
```

String.format se usa para que los días y meses tengan un 0 delante si son de un solo dígito y coincidan con el formato BASIC_ISO_DATE. `%02d` hace que se formateen así.

Comment: bro siempre me dice que es invalida

Comment: A ver como escribiste el código, agrégalo a tu pregunta.

Comment: ya lo modifique

Comment: En general funciona, lo que ocurre es que el formato BASIC_ISO_DATE, necesita que los nros. de día y mes que tengan un 0 delante. Así que editaré la respuesta para solucionar ese asunto.
Por otro lado, en tu código, si es inválida, igual luego se te va a mostrar que es válida. Lo que deberíás hacer es mover ese código a una función esValida(), y retornar true o false según lo sea.

Comment: lo voy a mirar :)

Comment: ya funciona solo que si la fecha es correcta bien pero si es incorrrecta te sale invalida y despues valida

Comment: Prueba a meter el System.out.println de válido dentro del try, después de la línea que ya tiene.